What is the input voltage of a typical 2.4 GHz WiFi antenna used at home?
I am trying to find the input voltage to a 2.4 GHz antenna used in a typical WiFi modem at home. Basically, I would say I want to disconnect the antenna from the modem and measure the voltage. I am trying to find the minimum, average and the peak value for this input voltage to the antenna.
Any help is much appreciated.

Are you talking about transmit or receive? If transmit, it's between 10 and 30dBm depending on the device and setting. You can assume the antenna to be 50 ohm, and you'll know the nominal voltage. However, if you want to know the peak/average ratio, you'll need to know the Wifi version since the modulation technique varies from PSK to QAM to OFDMA.

@RyujiAB1WX all modern Wifi standards (IEEE 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac/ax) do OFDM (not OFDMA – that's a multi-access scheme based on OFDM) with modulations for subcarriers BPSK, QPSK; 16-/64-/256-/1024-QAM, and at 2.4 GHz, there used to be a a DSSS mode (802.11b) with the sequences modulating (D)BPSK and (D)QPSK). Why I mention that: what's relevant there is that  OFDM systems like modern Wifi have both very non-constant envelope (read: voltages), due to their multicarrier nature, which makes this question not possible to answer by looking at the individual modulation scheme.

(@RyujiAB1WX because I understand you're a bit of deeply interested in things like these: if you want to know how the amplitude distribution for, say, a single-carrier QAM system is, you would pick a few (in the information-theoretical sense) typical sequences of symbols, pulse-shape them and do statistics on that. For a multi-carrier system, where the symbols on the individual carriers are independently random, you just do the classical trick of saying "Wait, I add complex, independently identically distributed values? The central limit theorem tells me that should approach a normal …

@RyujiAB1WX … distribution with increasing number of summands, i.e. with higher number of subcarriers!" And that's exactly what happens in practice: You can make very good calculations on the Peak-to-Average-Power-Ratio (PAPR), and how frequently a given maximum PAPR gets exceeded, from looking at the normal distribution. And that's how you design the analog transmit chain, which is always stuck in the tension between being power-efficient and being high in dynamic range. Set a maximum rate of OFDM symbols you compress/clip (which the error correction / ARQ needs to solve), derive PA budget)

@MarcusMüller I knew some of that, but I didn't know if people gave up on getting analytical solutions and reverted to CLT. The last time I checked these things was probably around 2001 (I was following both IEEE Info Theory society and MTT). So, in this case, has the variance of that distribution more or less steadily increased with the newer generation modulation+MA system?

@RyujiAB1WX I don't know about "giving up" (that sounds so negative!), but consider this: We know that in an N-carrier OFDM system, where each carrier individually and the sum are power-limited, there's N "worst-case PAPR" data vectors, ignoring "phase shift applied to the whole OFDM frame at once, which doesn't change envelope": take the total allowed power, divide it by N, take the square root and assign it to every single OFDM subcarrier: that's a constant in all N bins, you IDFT the constant, you get all the power in the first bin. You can then repeat that same math for all N frequencies

/ modulations of the constant and concentrate the power in one bin. Frankly, that's not a case you actually need to care for: Assume you were using the same constellation on all subcarriers, and it's rotationally symmetrical with $4$ rotations (e.g. $M$-QAM). Then, there's $N$ "prototype" worst-case OFDM signals, times $4$ (because that's the possible number of rotations that yield the same peak), so $4N$; but there's $M^N$ possible OFDM symbols, so only a fraction $4N/(M^N)$ of symbols have this extremely bad case of concentration; let's go very-small OFDM with $N=32, M=4$, then that's only

$2^7/({2^2}^{32})=2^{-57}$ of total symbols. So, on average, you can't deal with one symbol that occurs every $2^{57}$ random data symbols! You'll simply ignore that problem and go like "OK, a) it won't happen in the lifespan of the standard and b) when that happens, I send the packet again, but with the packet counter increased, so that's not going to happen again". Same calculations can be done for the second-to-worst, third-to-worst and so on, but because $N=32$ is small for real-world OFDM systems, but large for CLT, you can just say "Oh, these happen to be the tail probabilities of the

normal distribution, down to a precision that's more than good enough". Since you can bound the error you make, that's as much an analytical solution to the problem as trying to combinarically try to find the probabilities considering the actually used constellations, channel coding, fixed header things and whatnot. And it's a fair bit easier :)

So the distribution derived with the CLT is used mostly to estimate the chance of the tail events, which the CLT is usually terrible at. But considering the other sources of symbol/bit errors like interference from other terminals or fading, inaccuracy in the small probability of random errors may be of little consequence.

The CLT absolutely is not terrible at upper-bounding tail probabilities! Exactly, a statement like "in fewer than 10⁻⁹ cases, we will damage a symbol" is usually more than good enough for practical design, and as soon as we get into regions where these probabilities are large enough to make your network interface observably worse, we're not in the long tails anymore, but more like in less than three standard deviations – and now do that with N=48, N=52, N=108 , N=240 or even N=480 (as in Wifi) summands, and you'll see that the usual formulations of CLT are plenty sufficient.


I am trying to find the input voltage to a 2.4 GHz antenna used in a typical WiFi modem at home. Basically, I would say I want to disconnect the antenna from the modem and measure the voltage.

An antenna works at the radio frequency – you need a measurement device with a bandwidth of more than 2.4 GHz for that to make sense. Do you have an oscilloscope with > 4.8 GHz sampling rate? Otherwise, you can't measure voltages at 2.4 GHz antennas.

I am trying to find the minimum, average and the peak value for this input voltage to the antenna.

Average is trivial: 0 V. This is RF – it's alternating, zero mean voltage, by physics.
Minimum = - Maximum; this is communication at a carrier much higher than the modulation bandwidth, so the minimum voltage is simply the same as the maximum voltage, but with opposite sign.
Minimum absolute voltage would be 0 V again.
Average absolute voltage would depend on how many packets you send, with what data, to stations how far away – it's just proportional to the average square-root output power, and that is highly variable. Wifi doesn't use a constant-envelope modulation!
The other values: you can go from the characteristic impedance of the transmission line connecting the antenna, which might be 50Ω, and derive the voltage from the output power of your Wifi transmitter. Which is limited by law (probably 100 mW).

I am somehow guessing that the OP wanted to know the RMS and absolute instantaneous peak.

@RyujiAB1WX I could only comment on the RMS: that would be the average absolute value; i.e., just proportional to the average square root of output power, with feedline impedance definiting the proportionality
